# How can I define MATLAB function local variable type qualifiers / memory section in generated code?

Tags: matlab, code-generation

I am generating C code with Embedded Coder from a **MATLAB function** block. Because of memory constraints of my target, I need the local variables to be in the 'far' memory section, i.e. the definition of local variables in the generated code should look something like:

```
void fcn(...) {
  far double x[9];
  ...
}
```

I tried defining custom storage classes and specify `far` as a qualifier, but the whole generated code does not once contain the `far` keyword. I'd be happy for any suggestions on how to accomplish this.